# WCF basicHttpBinding with username & password in config file

Tags: wcf, basic-authentication

I have an existing WCF service, written in C#, which is hosted in an own process (not in IIS). Now I want to re-configure this service, so that the following requirements are met:

1. It has to use **basicHttpBinding**
2. It has to use **SSL**
3. **No code changes**, just changes in the service's and client's .exe.config file
4. **Username and password authentication**; as there is only one known client, a single hard-coded username/password would be sufficient

I have already searched pretty much but it seems that 4. and 3. are not possible in this combination. The ideal thing would be if one could just hard-code a username and password in the service's .exe.config file. Is this possible at all?

If yes, how would such a config file look like?

If no, what would be feasible alternatives, meeting requirements 1.-3. and what would their config file look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 1 through 3 try the following (Really no code changes just configuration and setup):

[SSL with Self-hosted WCF Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24027/SSL-with-Self-hosted-WCF-Service)

However 4, I think, will be impossible without code changes you will need to provide that user name/password to the service somehow and then on the service do a check for it. Configuration wont save you there, need to roll up your sleeves and put down some C# .NET!

Comment: Thanks, that confirmed my suspicion. I decided to go for X.509 client certificate authentication instead of username/password.

Comment: Sounds like you have a plan. =)